# What is the public portion of a base 64 encoded X509 certificate

Tags: certificate

Its not about how i get it, but its fine if you tell me also, but i simply dont know what this is:

> If "asymmetric", the Value parameter must be set to the public portion
>   of a base 64 encoded X509 certificate.

I have the certificate in the MMC.exe in windows and under export i have found out that i can export a .cer file without the private key. This file .cer is just a file containing text.

```
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------

BASE64 I ASSUME
-------------------------------
```

is it the content of this file, all of it, the stuff between the lines or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 encoded bytes that compose a struct with this information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Structure_of_a_certificate

The most essential parts, functionally: your public key, your name, and the signature (of those) by your CA ( that is, a trusted third party vouching that the person having the corresponding private key is the specified name ).